# how to get the column names and display Sql java

Tags: java, information-schema

obtain the names of the columns in a table and display it in java with Sistem Print

I have this code that gets the names of the columns

SELECT Column_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Table_Name =table

Comment: Please edit your question, its quite difficult to understand what you are asking

Comment: I apologize I do not speak English so I can hardly comment

Comment: edit it now, I hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

What you have is very database vendor specific.
For something that will work on all databases, I'd suggest executing 'select * from tablename where 1 = 0'  and then inspecting the ResultsetMetaData.